# Can't create users using PUT method in another Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, http

I'm trying to create users in another site from my site in wordpress but it does not work:

```
$response = wp_remote_post('http://ip-server:8083/client-services/create', array(
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => array(
                    'idNumber' => '1062125775',
                    'idType' => 'CO3',
                    'firstName' => 'Peter',
                    'secondName' => 'Scott',
                    'lastName' => 'Blunt',
                    'secondLastName' => 'Jhonson',
                    'gender' => 'M',
                    'email' => 'petersc@yandex.com',
                    'birthday' => '636440400000',
                    'source' => 'app',
                    'user' => 'petersc',
                    'location' => array('city' => array('id' => '17616', 'name' => 'Albany', 'region' => array('id' => '45', 'name' => 'New york'))),
                              ),
                    'cookies' => array() )
         );
         if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
            echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
        } else {
            echo 'Response:<pre>';
            print_r( $response );
            echo '</pre>';
        }
```

When I use post method in another server for create users it wotks..

Comment: What does your error message say?

Comment: As @AronCederholm has asked, what is the response/error?

Comment: does not show any error.

Comment: When i'm use postman it works but from wordpress don't

Comment: Well, do you not get any response at all? In what way doesn't it work? Can you find anything in your webserver logs on the receiving wordpress site?